# Vue.js 3 html dynamic class passing arguments based on computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, computed-properties, vue-composition-api

I use a dynamic class in Vue 3.

### In template

```html
// Within a loop
<div v-for="(item, index) in store.state.data" :key="`data-${index}`">
  <!-- I want to send item as an argument -->
  <div :class="myComputed"></div>
</div>
```

### In setup()

```js
const myComputed = computed(() => {
  const number = 500;
  return `bg-red-${number}`;
});
```

So far so good.

Now I want to send a variable to my computed property to have the class dynamic. By design Vue computed properties does not take an argument. Functions do, but when making it a function it's no longer reactive.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to make a computed property based on that store data by adding a field that contains the color :

```
const myData= computed(() => {
 return store.state.data.map(item=>{
         return   {...item,bgColor:`bg-red-${item.number}`};
     })
});
```

then loop through that property :

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in myData" :key="`data-${index}`">

  <div :class="item.bgColor"></div>
</div>
```

in Tailwindcss the string concatenation is not recommended because the purge css will remove that classes. [learn more](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html)